# Azure Devops release pipeline for local on-demand kubernetes deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, minikube

I am using Azure DevOps on cloud for my test microservice app. So I am using my own machine as an agent to build operations. And I created a kubernetes cluster on minikube with a hyperv driver. So I want to create a release pipeline and deploy to my local kubernetes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question, it is possible to create a release pipeline and you can deploy to your local kubernetes by referring to [link1](https://blog.geralexgr.com/azure/create-a-release-pipeline-and-deploy-to-local-kubernetes-cluster-with-azure-devops#:%7E:text=You%20can%20do%20that%20by,option%20for%20a%20kube%20cluster.&text=Get%20the%20output%20of%20the,add%20press%20verify%20and%20save.&text=Then%20you%20should%20go%20and%20create%20a%20release%20pipeline.) and [link2](https://stacksimplify.com/azure-aks/azure-devops-create-release-pipelines/) .

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can try to create a new Kubernetes service connection in your project with the "KubeConfig" or "Service Account" option. It should be from your Kubernetes cluster.

After the service connection created, you can use the "Kubectl" task in the release pipeline to deploy your local kubernetes.

For more information, you could refer to: [Kubernetes service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#kubernetes-service-connection).